# TK103, TCP data contains unknown string

Tags: java, tcp, geolocation, gps

I am working on a code that gets location from a GPS tracker to a server, the GPS tracker uses `TK103` as it's `TCP` communication protocol and it works fine.

The device sends proper data stream something like,

```
(057045144658BP05357857045144658180301A0604.8437N08018.7523E000.0002656000.0001000000L00000000)
```

But recently i saw this data stream contains some other format, may be another data stream but same command `BP05` as follows,

```
(057045144658BP05357857045144658,{413,1,61540,13292}{413,1,61540,15608}{413,1,61540,13247},01000000)
```

Device sends second data stream continuously for some time and then fall back to the previous one, this happens multiple times. Same string every time, no changes.

I use a `Java Netty` server as the `TCP` server.

What is this second data string and why this happens, how can i avoid this ? any suggestion is highly appreciated.